# Visual display of multiple comparisons test

Tags: data-visualization, multiple-comparisons

Suppose, the data below shows the mean response time on a task for respondents among four different groups:

```
A     B     C    D  
1.2   2.3   4.5  6.7
```

In order to assess which one of the means are different from one another I do a multiple comparisons test (after an omnibus ANOVA test is cleared) and the multiple comparisons test tells me that the mean for group D is significantly different from the ones for groups A and B and no other pair of differences is significantly different.

What is the best way to present this information visually?

Comment: Boxplot for each group with brackets above looks great, and you also display variability of data...(or instead of brackets you can use notches). If you have basic skills with "R" I can provide you working code.

Comment: Two issues with a boxplot. (a) It can be a challenge to interpret the plot for a non-technical audience (especially for someone who has never seen a boxplot) (b) it does not scale well if I have lots of such mulltiple-comparisons test. Imagine doing the above for 20 such tests in which case a table with 20 rows with suitable emphasis/visualization seems compact relative to 20 boxplots.

Comment: Two questions: 1-What exactly do you want to show, basic data, the multiple comparisons, the comparison's differences, all of the above? 2-What is the visualizations purpose and audience? Data exploration for you or explanation for a non-tech audience (if both you probably need two viz's).  Also, you mention that the mean for D is different than A & B, what about C?

Comment: 1. Right now my goal is to show the means and just draw the attention to the ones that are different. 2. The audience is not statistically aware and showing them a table of means with an emphasis on the ones that are different seems to be the right approach to me.

Comment: How many points do you have? With just 4, it's going to be difficult to show why D is different but C is not. For this, I'd almost do a simple dot-plot with a different symbol for D since it is statistically different.

Comment: Maybe you can try to make a little explanation how to look at it. It is not necessary to be a "rocket scientist" to understand boxplot. Do not pamper you audience :)

Answer (score 4):

```r
iv <- c("A","B","C","D")
dv <- c(1.2,2.3,4.5,6.7)
gp <- c(1,1,1,2)

par(mai=c(1,1,0,0))
plot(dv, gp, axes=F, xlab="Average time", ylab="Grouping based on 
                   \n mean comparison",
     ylim=c(0,3), xlim=c(0,7), pch=16)
text(dv, gp-.2, iv)
axis(side=2, label=c("i", "ii"), at=c(1,2))
axis(side=1)
abline(h=c(1,2),col="blue",lty=3)
```

Provide a footnote: **Means on the same horizontal reference line are not statistically different from each other. Alpha = 0.05, Bonferroni adjustment**

[image]

And I really like this design because you can flexibly accomodate group means with multiple memberships. Like in this case, C is not different from D and also not different from A and B:

```r
iv <- c("A","B","C", "C", "D")
dv <- c(1.2,2.3,4.5, 4.5, 6.7)
gp <- c(1,1,1,2,2)

par(mai=c(1,1,0,0))
plot(dv, gp, axes=F, xlab="Average time", ylab="Grouping based on 
            \n mean comparison",
     ylim=c(0,3), xlim=c(0,7), pch=16)
text(dv, gp-.2, iv)
axis(side=2, label=c("i", "ii"), at=c(1,2))
axis(side=1)
abline(h=c(1,2),col="blue",lty=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question and follow-up comments, I'd start with a dot-plot. They're quick and easy (even in Excel).  Here's s sample with your data:

[image: DotPlot]

This chart type scales well, handles large numbers of data points well and is very easy to understand-even to a non-tech audience.

Answer (score 1):

Point is, that **your dataset is too small** (4 groups 5 values each). The means obtained from such data are not very accurate representative values for each group - and therefore **you should not run ANOVA** to make inference about differences among group.

---

***One thing is to be understandable to the audience but more important is to be scientifically accurate.***

---

I suggest to solve this issue by **Kruskal-Wallis** followed by multiple comparisons.

**Boxplots** (with ***medians***) is probably the most used graphical representation of multiple comparisons of groups. To display differences you either make **brackets** above pairs which are statistically different and add (`***`-symbols or `N.S.`) This looks good if you have *small number of groups*. Or can make **notches** on each boxplot (very helpful in *large number of groups*) by which anyone will found desired comparison be eye.

---

You may created boxplots for example in `R`:

```r
data <- data.frame(value=c(rnorm(60), rnorm(20)+3), 
    group=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=20))

              value group
    1  -1.206926025     A
    2  -0.311125313     A
    3   1.336579675     A
    ......
    21  1.543827796     B
    22 -1.874257866     B
    ......
    80  4.383037868     D
    etc.  

boxplot(data$value ~ data$group, notch=TRUE,
    col = "red", xlab="group", ylab="value")
```

[image]

Boxplots shows **median** values instead of mean.
I strongly suggest to **not display ONLY mean values** for each group. Raw data are the last possibility.