# Visualize multiple 2 sample t-tests

Tags: python, t-test, data-visualization, paired-data

First time on cross validated - so if my question is not clear enough, please let me know.

I have 2 groups of websites - experimental and control. Each of these groups has many float variables I perform t-tests on - count of ads, number of input boxes, outbound links are 3 out of the 15 variables I compare in preliminary analysis. How do I visually show the information of all t-tests in a single graph/ is it even possible? Say, outboundlinks is more in experimental, ads more in control and so on.

I also have ks-tests for differences in distribution and the mannwhitneyu test for non-parametric comparison. Again, is there a way to visually show the information of all ks-tests (or MWU tests) in their single (respective) graphs?

Since the actual data is confidential, I am including sample data.

```
data = {'category':['group1', 'gropu1', 'group1', 'gropu1', 'group1', 'gropu2', 'gropu2', 'gropu2', 'gropu2', 'gropu2'],
        'metric1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        'metric2':[5, 6, 9, 8, 2, 1, 4, 4, 8, 2],
        'metric3':[1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 9, 7, 8, 5, 7]}
```

Note that these are all paired tests - NOT ANOVA. There are multiple paired tests for the same 2 groups. For better understanding, let's say group1 is females and group2 is males. And metric1 is education, metric2 is income, metric3 is lifespan. I did paired t-tests and found that in all 3 cases, the difference between males and females is significant. Short of writing the differences and p-values, is a graphical representation possible of all those paired t-tests?

Comment: Are the websites also paired? Can you show us some (simulated, mock-up) data with similar structure to yours, so we can experiment?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I apologize - I was moving and couldn't get around to editing it till now. 
P.S. Added a small mock-up data. I have 11 such metrics after dimensionality reduction and I perform ks-test, mannwhitney u test, and t-test to check the differences

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen what do you mean when you ask are the websites paired?

Comment: I mean paired, as in a "paired t test". Maybe the web sites are very different im some ways---number of users, theme, ... which make comparison difficult? In that case you couls pair two similar sites, and use one as treatment, the other as control.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen They *are* all paired tests. There are multiple paired tests for the same 2 groups. For better understanding, let's say group1 is females and group2 is males.  And metric1 is education, metric2 is income, metric3 is lifespan. I did paired t-tests and found that in all 3 cases, the difference between males and females is significant. I can't just write the difference and p-values for every such test. What I need is a graphical representation of all those paired t-tests.

Comment: Please add this new information to the post as an edit. We prefer posts to be self-contained, and not everybody reads comments

Comment: There are some examples at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72956/visual-display-of-multiple-comparisons-test

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen There is a significant difference in how the problem is set up. The OP in the other question is comparing between 4 groups on one score (a single test). Translating that problem here, I am testing the difference between 2 groups for different sets of 15 scores. (So, in essence, for them, it'll be like 15 ANOVAs, just as it is 15 t-tests for me)